Get or set layer display parameters using Python (reading documentation general question)
I'm having issues with finding data in QGIS Documentation so I wanted to ask how to access display parameters of layer (get existing values and change/update them).
I know that layer symbol can be accessed with something like that
symLr = layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(0) #read top symbol for layer
prp = symLr.properties() #reading existing into variable - left for later
prp['line_width'] = '5' #change/update property
symLr.setPenCapStyle(Qt.FlatCap) #set one of properties in layer
# add 2nd symbol to layer
layer.renderer().symbol().appendSymbolLayer(QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayer().create(prp))

There is different story with labelling, where we have "settings" instead of "properties".
lblSet = layer.labeling().settings()
lblSet.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Line
lblSet.placementFlags = 9
layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lblSet)) #use labelling

I found pieces of code somewhere here in other questions/answers or parts of code in work, but really struggle to read documentation, to get to know things like: for labeling() use .settings() but for symbol .properties(), why for label placement I have to use object, despite <LabelPlacement.Line: 2> (for placement flag I can use only value...).
I have also tried setting parameters using:
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('tmp')
p = QgsProperty()
p.setStaticValue(20)
pc.setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.LabelDistance, p)

But it only work if I set it as Expression: p.setExpressionString('20'), not StaticValue (no p.setValue and p.value=20 isn't working)
It seems like there is quite a few options to set up all those layer/label parameters (properties/settings), but when it come to practical (get or set them) none of the "similar" approaches are working, and I'm struggling to get answers i.e. about anchoring here.
It might be inconsistent QGIS developer approach (or dead StackExchange for GIS), but I really hope it's just me not reading documentation well enough.
